# Wordpress not working after PHP update

Tags: raspbian-buster, php, mysql, wordpress

I recently upgraded PHP5.X to PHP7.3 on my Pi 3 and also moved to Raspbian Buster from Jessie.

Now I get this message when I try to open the port 80 where I could earlier see my Wordpress site.

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

I use Apache and MariaDB and these are working. I installed `Php7.3-mysql` as well.

PHP is working correctly. I created a test.php file with this content `<?php echo “hello world”; ?>` and it works on the browser.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**So, how I resolved it!**

I removed Wordpress, all bits of php (`purge php*`) and then started from scratch after a reboot. It worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

With Raspbian Buster you will find the needed sql extension in its repository with `apt list *php*sql*`. Just install it with:

```
rpi ~$ sudo apt install php7.1-mysql
```

Comment: I updated PHP to 7.3 now and installed php7.3-mysql. However, not getting the the issue fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to [update](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004096331-Your-PHP-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-MySQL-extension-which-is-required-by-WordPress) WordPress itself to PHP7. The old MySQL plugin doesn't support PHP7, and you should use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead.

Comment: thanks. Can you provide some pointers on how to do? I downloaded the latest Wordpress, but it too is not working.